# error: C2061: syntax error: identifier 'concurrent_vector<`template-type-parameter-1',`template-type-parameter-2'>'

Tags: c++, syntax-error, tbb

A code compiles/runs fine on Linux and macOS. On Windows 10, I'm compiling the code with Visual Studio 2017 toolchain, but I'm receiving this error:

> `...\deps\tbb-2020.3-win\tbb\include\tbb\concurrent_vector.h:680: error: C2061: syntax error: identifier 'concurrent_vector<'template-type-parameter-1','template-type-parameter-2'>'`

The error happens at this `concurrent_vector` template:

```cpp
    //! Copying constructor for vector with different allocator type
    template<class M>
    __TBB_DEPRECATED concurrent_vector( const concurrent_vector<T, M>& vector, const allocator_type& a = allocator_type() )
        : internal::allocator_base<T, A>(a), internal::concurrent_vector_base()
    {
        vector_allocator_ptr = &internal_allocator;
        __TBB_TRY {
            internal_copy(vector.internal_vector_base(), sizeof(T), &copy_array);
        } __TBB_CATCH(...) {
            segment_t *table = my_segment.load<relaxed>();
            internal_free_segments( table, internal_clear(&destroy_array), my_first_block.load<relaxed>() );
            __TBB_RETHROW();
        }
    }
```

The error happens inside the TBB headers:

```
C:\...\deps\tbb-2020.3-win\tbb\include\tbb\concurrent_vector.h
```

What could possibly be the cause?

Here is a more complete error log:

```
c:\users\m3\repos\3d-editor\editorlib\deps\tbb-2020.3-win\tbb\include\tbb\concurrent_vector.h(680): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'concurrent_vector<`template-type-parameter-1',`template-type-parameter-2'>'
c:\users\m3\repos\3d-editor\editorlib\deps\tbb-2020.3-win\tbb\include\tbb\concurrent_vector.h(1167): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'tbb::concurrent_vector<T,A>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\memory_resource(860): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pmr::_Intrusive_stack<std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::_Header,void>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\memory_resource(465): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pmr::_Intrusive_stack<std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource::_Pool::_Chunk,void>' being compiled
c:\users\m3\repos\3d-editor\editorlib\deps\tbb-2020.3-win\tbb\include\tbb\concurrent_vector.h(681): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
c:\users\m3\repos\3d-editor\editorlib\deps\tbb-2020.3-win\tbb\include\tbb\concurrent_vector.h(61): fatal error C1075: '{': no matching token found
jom: C:\Users\m3\repos\build-3dsceneeditor-Desktop_Qt_5_12_9_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\editorlib\Makefile.Debug [debug\openvdbutils.obj] Error 2
```

This code can be used to recreate the issue in combination with the `/Zc:__cplusplus` compiler flag in visual studio 2017:

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>
int main()
{
    tbb::concurrent_vector<int> vector;
    vector.push_back(1);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Error log]

Comment: That does not look like the full error message. The message should say why the compiler objects to that particular identifier in that particular context.

Comment: Is that error message edited? `template-type-parameter-1` isn't a valid type name. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, that's the actual error!

Comment: How are you instantiating this template? Please show a [mre]

Comment: See https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/274

Comment: @AlanBirtles Well, that's the error I'm getting =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a visual studio bug. From the [issue](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/274) on the TBB github respository the `/Zc:__cplusplus` compiler flag is the cause.

Enabling that flag causes [this code](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/eca91f16d7490a8abfdee652dadf457ec820cc37/include/tbb/tbb_config.h#L622) to use the c++14 `[[deprecated]]` attribute:

```
    #if (__cplusplus >= 201402L)
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED [[deprecated]]
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED_MSG(msg) [[deprecated(msg)]]
    #elif _MSC_VER
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED_MSG(msg) __declspec(deprecated(msg))
    #elif (__GNUC__ && __TBB_GCC_VERSION >= 40805) || __clang__
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED_MSG(msg) __attribute__((deprecated(msg)))
    #endif
```

Swapping this code around to always use the visual studio specific code seems to fix the problem:

```
    #if _MSC_VER
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED_MSG(msg) __declspec(deprecated(msg))
    #elif (__cplusplus >= 201402L)
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED [[deprecated]]
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED_MSG(msg) [[deprecated(msg)]]
    #elif (__GNUC__ && __TBB_GCC_VERSION >= 40805) || __clang__
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
        #define __TBB_DEPRECATED_MSG(msg) __attribute__((deprecated(msg)))
    #endif
```

A [smaller demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/c4vWqo) of the same problem is:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}

    template <typename X>
    [[deprecated]] Foo(const Foo<T>& a)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> x;
    return 0;
}
```

This only doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017, [it works in 2019](https://godbolt.org/z/xW5983) so the simplest fix is to update visual studio.

A [pull request](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/pull/299) has been created to fix this issue and [reported to Microsoft](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Adding-deprecated-to-a-templated-con/1232182), I wouldn't expect MS to fix it though as it is already fixed in 2019.

Comment: I think you can create a corresponding PR for TBB repository to save next guys from this pain ...

Comment: @user3405291 Yes, just updating my visual studio to the latest version to make sure that isn't an easier fix first

Comment: @user3405291 PR created

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/274) a short fix would be to downgrade to **TBB 2020 Update 1** on Windows. Thanks to @AlanBirtles